# Clear styles of last li content

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="url">Title</a></li>  
        ... trimmed
        <li> 
            <div class="pagination">
                <ul>
                   <li class="PagedList-skipToNext">
                         <a href="/NextPage">> Next</a>
                   </li>
                </ul>
             </div> 
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I have a list as above, at the bottom of the list within `li` tag there is a pager, and it takes the style of `li` on the top however I want just `>Next` there in text format,without any styles.

I have tried to override the styles and no luck.

How can i clear the styles of `.pagination` block?

Thanks.

Comment: This heavily depends on your CSS. Why jQuery?

Comment: i have tried `removeAttr('style')` and didnt work.

Comment: Because it doesn't have style attribute? You can declare properties and overwrite other properties using CSS `.PagedList-skipToNext a { /* */ }`

Comment: If your CSS is applied to class then you could remove class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to "clear the styles" for a part of a document (oh how I wish there was). You'll have to keep overriding styles until everything looks good, or change the styles that affect the pager so that they don't affect it in the first place (for instance, by adding classes to all the other list elements and targeting those).

You can use Firebug or Chrome's developer tools to quickly see which style rules exactly are affecting your pager.

Answer (score 2):

Simply override any style you have defined in `.pagination` class:

```
.pagination a
{
  font-size: 10pt;
  color: red;
  /* any other property you want to override here... */ 
}
```

or just add a new class to that anchor tag like `<a href="/NextPage" class="next">> Next</a>`:

```
.next
{
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: red;
}
```